# pass multiple params to a groupby function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna do a custom function over a groupby, so for example if my data has the following format.

```
personid  jobid  start_date  end_date
1           1    2015-01-01  2016-01-30 
1           2    2016-01-01  2017-01-01
```

I wanna compute the overlap between the two dates of the two different jobs for the same person. Would it be wise to use

```
df.groupby(personid).agg(x)
```

But then how would i reference both start date and end date for different records in the function x.

The output of code would be something like

```
personid  overlap
1         30
```

Comment: Can one person overlap by 3 jobs? :D

Comment: No, it's always two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function where select first and last value of `start` and `end` datetime, get [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) and then find `length` of intersection by [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
def f(x):
    a = pd.date_range(x['start_date'].iat[0], x['end_date'].iat[0], unit='d')
    b = pd.date_range(x['start_date'].iat[-1], x['end_date'].iat[-1], unit='d')
    return pd.Series(len(np.intersect1d(a,b)), index=['overlap'])

df = df.groupby('personid').apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   personid  overlap
0         1      366
1         2        6
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date': [pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-01-05 00:00:00')], 'personid': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'end_date': [pd.Timestamp('2016-01-30 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-01-25 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2015-01-10 00:00:00')], 'jobid': [1, 2, 1, 2]})
print (df)
    end_date  jobid  personid start_date
0 2016-01-30      1         1 2015-01-01
1 2016-01-01      2         1 2015-01-01
2 2015-01-25      1         2 2015-01-01
3 2015-01-10      2         2 2015-01-05
```

Comment: Veeeery interesting, yeah i know how to find the range and the intersect, i was just looking for the iat function. TBH i still don't get how it works. But thanks a lot

Comment: Glad can help. What is exactly unlear? I try explain it.

Comment: Really nice solutions, this one definitely work if only 2 jobs for each person id, but do you need 4 job for each person which each job overlap with another job but without 3 job overlap

Comment: @PhongPhung - yes exactly. It works only if each `personid` have `2 jobid`.

Comment: @iyadalaqel - Have always each `personid` only `2 jobid` ? Or is possible more?

Comment: so when you use the apply function, it deals with each group as a different dataframe and you can access the rows of that group/dataframe just by index?

Comment: no its always 2 jobid, that works perfectly for my need.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can use `print (x)` in `f` for check it.

Comment: if you want to know more about pandas, this guide cover nearly everything you need https://tomaugspurger.github.io/. @jezrael `iat` was really nice, before knowing your solution i was have to use the index, and refer back the base dataframe